# adverbial phrase inversion

Tags: adverbials

I am teaching English at a high school in South Korea. I am not an American but Korean. Recently, I was teaching adverbial phrase inversion as a grammatical point. My question is which of these following sentences is right:

> In the pool were my sisters swimming.
>
> In the pool were swimming my sisters

I just feel that the first one is right, but I am not sure. Would you help me out with my problem? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Neither sentence is something a native speaker would say.  More natural would be _My sisters were swimming in the pool._  If you really want _in the pool_ at the beginning, I would suggest _In the pool, my sisters were swimming._

Comment: Welcome to the site @handrickhong.  Based on your role as a teacher of English as a second language, I thought you might find [this stack](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) has a lot of helpful questions and answers.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn It's not about idiom or register but grammar. All three forms of the sentence are perfectly grammatical and make sense, **with attendant nuances**. It is up to the author to shift the emphasis according to context.

Answer (score 1):

> In the pool were my sisters swimming.

This could be made technically correct by the addition of a comma:

> In the pool were my sisters, swimming.

"Swimming" is effectively an adjective.  Your sisters are in the pool and they are swimming.  A native speaker probably wouldn't use a one-word word gerund like that, but would with longer phrases:

> In the back seat sat the dog, eating my sandwich.
>
> Downstairs was my date, waiting impatiently.

The poetic inversion of subject and prepositional phrase is often used to make the sentence sound humorous or otherwise unusual.

> In the pool were swimming my sisters

is completely correct technically, but just not something a native speaker would say aloud.  You might see it in some flowery written text somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't always need to move the verb.

Original:

> My sisters were swimming in the pool

Apply adverbial phrase inversion by moving the adverbial phrase *in the pool* to the beginning of the sentence:

> In the pool my sisters were swimming.

Moving the verb (*In the pool were swimming my sisters*) is not wrong as such, but an unnecessary complication in this case. Sometimes, you have no choice. For example:

> He had never missed a day at work

becomes

> Never had he missed a day at work

Comment: thanks for the help! But I need to answer the questions students ask me anyway. So would you look at these two sentences and decide which one is correct grammatically? First, On the corner was standing a red-haired girl, second, on the corner was a red-haired girl sanding. and if possible, would you explain why one of them is correct and the other is not?

Comment: I would go with the first, partly because the second one looks like a question and partly because it contains an unnecessary movement of the verb. To be fair, this is to some extent my preference to aim for simplicity. In some circumstance (poetry, for example), the second may be more appropriate.

Comment: I'd appreciate it. It's been a great help for me.

Comment: A "native speaker" might say something like "In the pool were my sisters, swimming (contentedly/as if nothing was wrong/as if the sky was not about to fall in/for all they were worth/ etc.)"